# Is there a simple way to notify users about new posts on the site?

Tags: 7, rules, notifications

I want my users to be able to "subscribe" to new content that is posted on my site.

I've looked at the [Notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/notifications) and [Subscriptions](https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions) modules and they are just massive! I've also looked at Simplenews (which which has a *very* attractive name), but it seems targeted towards distribution of a custom newsletter and not sending out general notifications about new content posted on the site.

Is there simple a way to set up a *rule* (by means of the Rules module) to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes you can do this through Rules. In following URL all the steps are mentioned that you need to follow to get this done. http://drupal.cocomore.com/blog/rules-admin-notifications-part-2-new-comments-and-content I am sure it would help you to configure notification about new posts on your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the core Trigger/Actions couple for such an easy job. Here is what you do:

1. Through `/admin/config/system/actions`, create the action, namely "Send e-mail..." and click *Create*.
2. Fill in information such as e-mail address and message.
3. Enable the **Trigger** module.
4. Through `/admin/structure/trigger`, choose your action.

You are now good to go!

Answer (score 4):

You may consider the [Notify](https://drupal.org/project/notify) module, which is a lightweight framework for sending out periodic notifications about new site content to users and admins.

From the project page:

> The notify module allows users to subscribe to periodic emails which include all new or revised content and/or comments of specific content types, much like the daily newsletters sent by some websites.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

1. Create a field (probably a checkbox) in user account settings to subscribe for notification.
2. Then create a rule condition using `hook_rules_condition_info()` to check whether he has subscribed or not.
3. Create a rule to send a email notification when a new node is saved and add your custom condition to it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, this can be done with [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views). Create a View either as a block or as a page of the appropriate content type, sort, filter and change as desired. Once as a block for example, you can put it any number of pages to show the most recent content.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tutorial "[How to use Rules to notify users about new or updated posts on a Drupal site?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/107#node-108)", which explains how to use the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module for this, together with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. What follows is a summary of what's included in this tutorial.

> You could also use the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module for this. So that you have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module create message "entities" (which is what you get if you use the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module). And then just use the power of [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display those messages that got created in the format you need (page, block, etc).
>
> Here is a blueprint of what you'd need:
>
> 1. Define an appropriate Message type, using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. Think of Message types as similar to "Content types", which will be used to create Messages, similar to nodes.
> 2. Create a rule with a Rules Action "Create entity" (of type "Message"). Refer to the answer in '*[Which user related token(s) can be used to create a Rule for setting up a message type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219680/)*' for some examples.
> 3. Make sure to also add a Rules Action to pass any relevant tokens, via the Rules module, as *Replacement tokens* that you can use in your Message type you created with the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. Refer to [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/109) for more details on this.
> 4. Use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display the created messages in the format you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I am the maintainer of [flag_notify()](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_notify) (for Drupal 7). Using the great UI of flags() it can concentrate on the logic of the notifications that would be too long or impossible to implement with rules.

It has some nice feature as (1) you can set up default notification for new users sitewise, and then each user can set their own default when they post a content or comment, (2) it has integration with Organic Group (if present), (3) it considers notification from sub-comments (when comments are organised hierarchically) and (4) it has hooks() that allow to personalise the notification message or the logic of the notification (e.g. if you want to exclude something too frequent).