# What's the difference between private message & message?

Tags: 7

In my user backend I have a tab named 'messages' (mysite.com/user/uid/messages) and a second named 'Private messages & invitation' (mysite.com/user/uid/contacts).

For what I see private messages is where users can message each others when there are trusted contact.

Now I want to know the use of 'Messages'. Also I've seen that there is two modules message & Privatemsg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Drupal Commons once out of curiosity, but it was a long time ago and my memory is fuzzy. I know both of those modules, so this is just an educated guess on how Commons is using them:

Private message is for messaging other users on the site. While Messages is used for notifications/alerts that tells you someone posted here or there, or someone liked your comment etc...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens as much as I would like to, asking for support in the past has not gone well for me. All I can do is hope that others will follow suit.

Answer (score 1):

By using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module, you can create your own custom "*Events logging*" (to register things that happened in a site).

A great sample of this you can find in [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), which uses the [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) module, to create such "*Events logging*". In this case in the format of an Order History, as shown in [this screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/commerce_message%20history.png) (from this module's project page).

The [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module is an amazing module, though there is not a lot of documentation about it. It is fully entity based, which implies that it perfectly (out of the box) integrates with modules such as [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). And to give you an idea of the kind of things you can use it for, have a look at the answers to:

- [How to create a basic message - notifications system displaying a real time message counter badge?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68867/how-to-create-a-basic-message-notifications-system-displaying-a-real-time-mess/210869#210869)
- [How to show message view containing own and following activity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222788/how-to-show-message-view-containing-own-and-following-activity/222800#222800)
- [How to integrate messaging into a custom module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202299/how-to-integrate-messaging-into-a-custom-module/202314#202314)
- [Is there a simple way to notify users about new posts on the site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116540/is-there-a-simple-way-to-notify-users-about-new-posts-on-the-site/221661#221661)