# Extended Audit logs

Tags: 8, security

I am using Audit log module for Drupal 8.5. But it looks the audits are very limited - i.e it audits only user updates and node updates. Not for creating templates, changing configurations, changing themes , creating pages, views etc. Since this site will be audited , I believe I might need more than this.

Any help on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module would be a possible solution to answer this question. Using this module, you can create your own custom "*Events logging*" (to register things that happened in a site).

About *Message types*: think of them as equivalent to Content types, whereas you create messages (instead of nodes) of a specific Message type (instead of Content type).

#### Example included in Commerce Kickstart

A great sample of this can be found in [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), which uses the [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) module, to create such "*Events logging*". In that case in the format of an Order History, as shown in [this screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/commerce_message%20history.png) (from this module's project page).

#### More info about the Message module

The [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module is an amazing module, it is fully entity based, which implies that it perfectly (out of the box) integrates with modules such as [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), etc.

Though there is ***not a lot of documentation about it*** (which is what makes it a hidden gem ...). A possible way to get started with it, and to get an idea of the kind of things it can be used for, is to have a look at the answers to:

- [How to create a basic message - notifications system displaying a real time message counter badge?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68867/how-to-create-a-basic-message-notifications-system-displaying-a-real-time-mess/210869#210869)
- [How to show message view containing own and following activity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222788/how-to-show-message-view-containing-own-and-following-activity/222800#222800)
- [How to integrate messaging into a custom module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202299/how-to-integrate-messaging-into-a-custom-module/202314#202314)
- [Is there a simple way to notify users about new posts on the site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116540/is-there-a-simple-way-to-notify-users-about-new-posts-on-the-site/221661#221661)

**Tutorials:**

- [What is Drupal's Message Stack and how do its modules work together?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/105)
- [How to allow users to manage their own Message Stack messages?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/82)
- [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/109)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Let me check out these information.

Comment: @Prabhushanmughapriyan any additional feedback?

Comment: I went over the docs you added. It was very useful. I am currently stuck on few things. I am trying to resolve it. I will get back to the forum if the problem persists. Thanks for checking.

Comment: @Prabhushanmughapriyan if very useful, how about marking this question as accepted? And post followup questions if needed?

Comment: from the sample i could not sense how can i track the changes done by a user - for ex - 1) user changed a setting 2) User added / uninstalled a module. Could you please throw some light on it.