# Commenting or replying a specific node without the possibility of commenting others?

Tags: comments

I built a website sort of like an online directory for restaurants in my home town, and I am letting the users to leave their reviews about a specific restaurant, and what I need is to give access to the manager or owner of a specific restaurant to reply those reviews or to leave a comment on his node "restaurant", and he cannot reply or comments other restaurants except his.
is their any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module would be a possible solution to answer this question. Using this module, you can create your own custom "*Reviews*", which can be used to store (save) the data about them in relevant (custom) fields such as dates, contact info, scores and what not).

About *Message types*: think of them as equivalent to Content types, whereas you create messages (instead of nodes) of a specific Message type (instead of Content type).

#### Example included in Commerce Kickstart

A great sample of this can be found in [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), which uses the [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) module, to create "*Events logging*". In that case in the format of an Order History, as shown in [this screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/commerce_message%20history.png) (from this module's project page).

#### More info about the Message module

The [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module is an amazing module, it is fully entity based, which implies that it perfectly (out of the box) integrates with modules such as [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), etc. And there is also quite a few questions about it on drupal.SE, many of them tagged with [message-stack](/questions/tagged/message-stack).

Though there is ***not a lot of documentation about it*** (which is what makes it a hidden gem ...). A possible way to get started with it, and to get an idea of the kind of things it can be used for, is to have a look at the answers to:

- [How to create a basic message - notifications system displaying a real time message counter badge?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68867/how-to-create-a-basic-message-notifications-system-displaying-a-real-time-mess/210869#210869)
- [How to show message view containing own and following activity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222788/how-to-show-message-view-containing-own-and-following-activity/222800#222800)
- [How to integrate messaging into a custom module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202299/how-to-integrate-messaging-into-a-custom-module/202314#202314)
- [Is there a simple way to notify users about new posts on the site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116540/is-there-a-simple-way-to-notify-users-about-new-posts-on-the-site/221661#221661)

**Tutorials:**

- [What is Drupal's Message Stack and how do its modules work together?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/105)
- [How to allow users to manage their own Message Stack messages?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/82)
- [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/109)